# Project reactor processors v3.X

Tags: spring, project-reactor

We are trying to migrate from 2.X to 3.X.
https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/375
We have used the EventBus as event manager in our application(Low latency FX system) and it works very well for us.

After the change we decided to take every module and create his own processor to handle event.
1. Does this use seems to be correct from your point of view? Because lack of document at the current stage and after reviewing everything we could we don't really know what to do here
2. We have tried to use Flux in order to perform action every X interval
For example: Market is arriving 1000 for 1 second but we want to process an update only 4 time in a second. After upgrading we are using:

Processor with buffer and sending to another method.
In this method we have Flux that get list and try to work in parallel in order to complete his task.
We had 2 major problems:
1. Sometimes we received Null event which we cannot find that our system is sending to i suppose maybe we are miss using the processor

```
    //Definition of processor
    ReplayProcessor<Event> classAEventProcessor = ReplayProcessor.create();

    //Event handler subscribing
    public void onMyEventX(Consumer<Event> consumer) {
       Flux<Event> handler = classAEventProcessor .filter(event -> event.getType().equals(EVENT_X));
       handler.subscribe(consumer);
   }
```

in the example above the event in the handler sometimes get null.. Once he does the stream stop working until we are restating server(Because only on restart we are doing creating processor)

2.We have tried to us parallel but sometimes some of the message were disappeared so maybe we are misusing the framework

```
    //On constructor
   tickProcessor.buffer(1024, Duration.of(250, ChronoUnit.MILLIS)).subscribe(markets -> 
   handleMarkets(markets));

   //Handler
  Flux.fromIterable(getListToProcess())
        .parallel()
    .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
    .doOnNext(entryMap -> {
        DoBlockingWork(entryMap);
    })
    .sequential()
    .subscribe();
```

The intention of this is that the processor will wakeup every 250ms and invoke the handler. The handler will work work with Flux parallel in order to make better and faster processing.
*In case that DoBlockingWork takes more than 250ms i couldn't understand what will be the behavior

UPDATE:
The EventBus was wrapped by us and every event subscribed throw the wrapped event manager.
Now we have tried to create event processor for every module but it works very slow. We have used TopicProcessor with ThreadExecutor and still very slow.. EventBus did the same work in high speed
Anyone has any idea? BTW when i tried to use DirectProcessor it seems to work much better that the TopicProcessor

Answer (score 1):

Reactor 3 is built around the concept that you should avoid blocking as much as you can, so in your second snippet `DoBlockingWork` doesn't look good.

How are the events generated? Do you maybe have an listener-based asynchronous API to get them? If so, you could try using `Flux.create`.

For your use case of "we have 1000 events in 1 second, but only want to process 4", I'd chain a `sample` operator. For instance, `sample(Duration.ofMillis(250))` will divide each second into 4 windows, from which it will only emit the last element.

The reference guide is being written, as well as a page where you can find links to external articles and learning material.There's a preview of the WIP reference guide [here](http://next.projectreactor.io/docs/core/snapshot/reference/docs/index.html) and the learning resources page [here](http://next.projectreactor.io/learn).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am trying to avoid but this is example for "heavy action" that i have to parallel it somehow. After moving to v3.X the event bus cannot be used. I have tried to switch to TopicProcessor for every module instead of general EventBus for all modules but i saw it was really slow... Tried to give give him ThreadExecuter but still very very slow.
So now our events very slow and parallel not working very well. What you suggest we need to try? We really don't have a clue we have tried everything we can think of.. I was reading all documents that i have found

Comment: Do you think that i am doing something wrong with the processors? What is the diffrences between them?(DirectPrcessor for example)?
Hope i managed to explain what exctly am i using and need help with best practices to avoid mistakes and still have speed and high throughput like in EventBus